# trying using excel 2010 vba addressing "re-named" sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have some sheets i have renamed Templates and Loan Summary

how do I  address those in VBA so it recognizes them as an "Object" here is the code in question

```
    Sub CopyInfo()
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Templates.Range("A1:J9").Copy
    Sheet8.Range("A15").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

the error I get is "Object Required" so it isnt recognizing Templates as an object that has a .Range

Comment: try `Worksheets("Templates")`

Comment: man! that was quick and correct , thank you nomad!

Comment: If you want to use `Templates.Range()` instead of `Worksheets("Templates")` you need to change the code name. This is done by entering the code editor, opening the properties window (and selecting page from navigation, if needed), then change the name in the Properties.Name section.

Comment: Ah great that works too thanks Mistella

Comment: @j.doezer, FYI, if you add the "@" before the names (no space) the users will get notified about the comment(s)

Comment: @Mistella   that is good to know will do did you get notified with this one

Comment: @j.doezer Yep, I got a notification  :)